# Create App Engine Backend for Android - Google Tutorial

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine

I am following this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial/

At Setup App Engine Backend Application Project - Step 4, I am stumped. The Create button is grayed out. There is nothing told about configuring the App Engine SDK in any of the preceding steps. And, as you can see that I am in the process of learning this, I don't know any ways to solve this other than searching helplessly in the same tutorial.

If I 'configure sdks', the list is empty and I am led to this link https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads?csw=1

If this is the right direction, can anyone help me which one of the four platforms does this tutorial teach with? Can I choose any and still be able to follow the tutorial easily? In case yes, which one of the four Should I choose?

[image: Create Button Greyed Out]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial you are following uses the Java App Engine SDK. Download that and then configure the path to the location you've installed the SDK at. If you've downloaded Google Plugin for Eclipse instead (specified in the tutorial as required) it is already included and you should already have the App Engine SDK for Java.

Do keep in mind that if you want to go live and use Google Cloud Messaging like in the tutorial, you will need a Project Number and API key filled in. You can always do this later and leave it blank for now though. To add them later, edit them in GCMIntentService.java and MessageEndpoint.java respectively.

Comment: Thank You a lot! i guess that's all what i needed to know

Answer (score 0):

configure your appengine sdk location **/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.6/**

Comment: com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.6/ does not exist there. Am i missing something? is it something from here? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads?csw=1

If yes, which platform does this google tutorial follow? java, php, python or go?

Comment: Do you have any App Engine SDKs installed?  If you installed it through Eclipse, you should have a directory similar to the one in this answer, but with a different version number.  If you have not installed the SDK, you can do so through Eclipse (just as you installed the App Engine plugin).

Comment: Please tell me which one to install??? php, java, python or go? i cannot tell which one the tutorial is using

Comment: i am using java version.